# How do I configure spring security filter on Spring 3.1.3 for a springboot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application and I'm struggling to setup spring security.

Here's what I added on my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

Here's my SpringSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    //Authentication
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN").build();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("user")).roles("USER").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I tried a couple of tutorials on how to configure the filter, but I always reach some sort of issue like:

This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

Or there is some annotation that is missing, or the method in the tutorial is no longer available in the current version.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/"), mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/home"), mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/signup")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        return http.build();
    }
```

But then when I try to hit / or /home or /signup, I get the following:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

What am I missing to get it working properly?
I'm not using thymeleaf. It's just the regular JSP.
Here's the dependencies I got:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.6.0'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:5.3.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap-datepicker:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:font-awesome:5.15.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

If I just remove the spring security piece (the dependency and SpringSecurityConfig class) everything gets back to normal and I can access the pages back again.

Also, without the filter I added, when I try to reach localhost:8080 it brings me to the login page and I can login afterwards to the root page.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Spring boot earlier in the year and I quickly learned that as it's a rapidly evolving framework, most of the tutorials you find on the internet are either antiquated or contain non-best intended practices. I can't specifically tell you what you have done wrong here, but it looks like the particular configuration you are using is outdated for the current security module.

*Just a couple of tips I can think of:*

1. Utilise the official Spring documentation - the explanations are far more thorough than any tutorials available across blogs and websites: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html
2. Reference existing sample applications on the official Spring github - they often contain the bare minimum requirements for configurations of starter applications with specific requirements (i.e. Gradle for MVC in your case): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/java-configuration/hello-mvc-security

Hopefully both of these links contain the relevant information which helps solves your problem.